# How do I insert a related row into a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm completely stumped. I have two tables set up in my database, one called subjects and one called pages. I gave the pages a subject_id in my database to connect them to subjects. I've dynamically displayed a nav containing the subjects and there child pages. I've also created a few php files that delete subjects, edit subjects, and edit pages. I've now added a link onto each subject so that when you click on the subject, it takes you to a page where, hopefully, I'll be able to add a new page under the chosen parent subject. It's also worth noting that i am sending the parent subject id in the link to add the page.
Here's the fraction of code that i believe is somehow giving me problems:

```
if(empty($errors)){
$id = mysql_prep($_GET['subj']);
$menu_name = mysql_prep($_POST['menu_name']);
$position = mysql_prep($_POST['position']);
$visible = mysql_prep($_POST['visible']);
$content = mysql_prep($_POST['content']);

$subject = get_subject_by_id($id));//This fetches the subject id from the db

$query = "INSERT INTO
pages WHERE subject_id = $subject
(
menu_name, position, visible, content
) VALUES (
'{$menu_name}', {$position}, {$visible}, '{$content}'
)";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db_connect);      
if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1){

echo "<p>suceess</p>";
} else { ....
```

I know this is out of context but i thought someone might have some luck by spotting the problem. If anybody has ANY insight on this I would appreciate it.

Comment: It would help if you explained exactly what problem you are having. What in particular is not working and how should it work?

Comment: Scott, what error are you gettign?

Comment: mysql_prep is a convenience function in php used to sanitize user input

Comment: @mvrak [No such function exists in PHP](http://php.net/mysql-prep)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a where clause in an insert statement.

Without the where clause the table will get the inserted row.  If you are trying to update an existing row, which would justify a where clause, then you need to use an update statement.

Comment: @NullUserException - mysql_prep() takes care of the quotes. 
I'm trying to insert a page table row in relation to subject table row. I have the subject id to work with, I just can't figure out how to connect the new page to page to the parent subject upon insert.

Answer (score 0):

the correct `INSERT` syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO pages (subject_id, menu_name, position, visible, content) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

of course, bind with the appropriate parameters and **do not use string interpolation**.

Comment: right, i tried that and got it to insert, but I can't seem to get it to insert in relation to Page Id. For example, I want the the page's subject_id to equal the Subjects Id upon insertion

Comment: that's why you have to add `subject_id` as one of the parameters.